# How to check if elements in a Pandas Series of lists are all part of another list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series of lists of arbitary length:

```
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,6], [7,8,9,10]])
```

and a list of elements

```
l = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
```

I want to return all elements of the series `s` which has all values contained in `l`, otherwise `None`. I want to do something like this but apply it to each element in the series:

```
s.where(s.isin(l), None)
```

So the output would be a series:

```
pd.Series([[1,2,3], None, None])
```

Comment: are all lists in the series equal length?

Comment: Edited to reflect, no.

Answer (score 2):

you can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the series, use `isin` with l and use [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) with the parameter level=0 (equivalent to `groupby.all` on the index).

```
print(s.explode().isin(l).all(level=0))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

use this Boolean mask in `where` to get your expected result

```
s1 = s.where(s.explode().isin(l).all(level=0), None)
print(s1)
0    [1, 2, 3]
1         None
2         None
dtype: object
```

Thanks to a comment of @mozway, *the parameter level=0 in all is being deprecated*, so the solution would be with `groupby.all`

```
s1 = s.where(s.explode().isin(l).groupby(level=0).all(), None)
```

Comment: NB. `all(level=0)` is getting deprecated, the new syntax is `groupby(level=0).all()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic of python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
s.apply(set(l).issuperset)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Then use `where` to modify the non matching rows using the previous output as mask:

```
s.where(s.apply(set(l).issuperset), None)
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1         None
2         None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

@TomNash, you can combine `all` function with `listcomprehension`:

```
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

l = [1,2,3,6,7,8]

final_list = []
for x in s:
    if all(item in l for item in x):
        final_list.append(x)
    else:
        final_list.append(None)

print(final_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

`[[1, 2, 3], None, None]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [4,6], [7,8,9,10]])
l = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
new_series = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    s_in_l = 0
    for j in range(len(s[i])):
        if s[i][j] not in l:
            s_in_l = s_in_l + 1
    if s_in_l == 0:
        new_series.append(s[i])
    else:
        new_series.append(None)
new_series = pd.Series(new_series)
print(new_series)
```

output:

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1         None
2         None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element of `s` is subset of `l` by [`.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) function, as folllows:

```
s.apply(lambda x: x if set(x).issubset(l) else None)
```

or make use of numpy function [`setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), as follows:

```
s.apply(lambda x: x if (len(np.setdiff1d(x, l)) == 0) else None)
```

Result:

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1         None
2         None
dtype: object
```